# Function of NaCl in yeast shuttle prep of plasmids

Tags: molecular-biology, dna-isolation

What is the role of NaCl in plasmid isolation from yeast cells using plasmid rescue solution? If the basic theory behind the method is alkaline lysis, then we is NaCl used and not NaOH?

Answer (score 1):

High salt concentrations will cause the proteins and lipids to precipitate out, as in [salting out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salting_out). Free Na+ ions may also bind the negatively charged DNA backbone and give the molecules a neutral net charge, allowing them to concentrate as well.